# Where to set reserved store app names?

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I reserved several names from my windows 10 universal app, from the web dashboard, each corresponding to the languages that my app supports.

Problem is that I don't see where, in the store, to set those reserved names. In the description fields of each languages, I don't see a "title" field as I would have expected.

So where to set the translated reserved names in the store ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the name of your app inside the `Package.appxmanifest` file by filling the [`DisplayName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/dn423240.aspx) field. This display name needs to be one of the names you have reserved at the dashboard.

When settings this name, you can not only enter strings but also references to your resource files.

So just store the name of you app (that you have also reserved at the dashboard) in your resource file and refer to it like this in the XML view of your manifest file:

```
<Properties>
    <DisplayName>ms-resource:AppName</DisplayName>
</Properties>
```

You can find [more details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454044.aspx#NotExistJustToMakeTheAElementVisible). Please ping me, if you need more information about localizing your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I will reserve same names as all the names in the app properties DisplayName. There is no formal and visible relation in the  dashboard between names in the manifest, and reserved names right ?

Comment: You are right, there is no way to directly connect the reserved names in the dashboard with the ones you choose in your manifest. But at least it has to be one of the reserved ones, otherwise your app certification will fail.